# i am migrating wicket version from1.5.3 to 8.7.0 in my application. getting noSuchmethoderror

Tags: wicket-8

stack trace

SEVERE: Exception starting filter [wicket]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: testclass.mountPage(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)V
    at com.ecs.test.web.wicket.FrameworkTestApplication.init(FrameworkTestApplication.java:67)
    at org.apache.wicket.Application.initApplication(Application.java:783)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:444)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.init(WicketFilter.java:368)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4591)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5233)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Comment: how about a [mcve]?

Comment: Try following each migration guide, step by step. Don't skip steps, and make each migration error free before moving on to the next. I managed to migrate from 1.3 to 7.8 by following those thouroughly. It can take a while to solve every error though. http://wicket.apache.org/start/wicket-8.x.html#migrate